# Python Requests getting inconsistent response code

Tags: python, python-requests

I am attempting to write a webscraper for the stats.nba.com website. Sometimes when I run a script, it comes out at as a 200 return code, but other times it becomes a 400 error code. I suspect that maybe it's takes a response sometimes, but not sure. Here is an example with four, but it's usually at a much bigger one.

Here is the code.

```
urls = ['http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoresummaryv2?GameID=0021500001', 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoresummaryv2?GameID=0021500002',
        'http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoresummaryv2?GameID=0021500003', 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoresummaryv2?GameID=0021500004']

for url in urls:
    r = requests.get(url)
    print r.url
    print r.status_code
```

Here's a sample response and I continue to get wildly inconsistent response codes.

```
http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoresummaryv2?GameID=0021500001
200
http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoresummaryv2?GameID=0021500002
400
http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoresummaryv2?GameID=0021500003
400
http://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoresummaryv2?GameID=0021500004
400
```

Comment: Perhaps `stats.nba.com` is trying to discourage web scraping, and disallows more than X requests per minute from the same client IP address.

Comment: I don't see where BeautifulSoup is used in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  need to pass a user-agent:

```
In [11]: for url in urls:
....:         r = requests.get(url, headers={"user-agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.92 Safari/537.36"})
   ....:      print(r.status_code)
   ....:     
200
200
200
200
```

No user-agent:

```
In [12]: for url in urls:
            r = requests.get(url)           
            print(r.status_code)   
....:     
200
400
400
400
```

I would also  consider adding a sleep between requests if I were you.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have been trying to figure this out on my own since Sunday! Why do user-agents need to be passed. I am just trying to make sure I understand. Thanks again!

Comment: a user agent header will make your request appear to be from a specific browser instead of a perl script. This will generally be better received by large websites that might not want people to scrape their data as you will look like a normal user to them. Check their t&c's allow you to do this.

Comment: @KellyRoper, no worries, a user-agent is used to identify yourself to the web server, you could use `headers={"user-agent":"Foobar"}` and you would get the same result in this case. Their robots.txt http://stats.nba.com/robots.txt does not contain any restrictions not do their ToS in relation to what is being scraped, the server just seems to want the user-agent header set.